# ant: How do I find the value of the -keep-going flag in a build file?

Tags: ant

I have an `ant` build file which calls `make`.  I would like to pass the `-k` (-keep-going) flag specified on the `ant` command line to `make`.

But I can't find the state of `-k` anywhere accessible from the build file.  It doesn't seem to be in the properties or in the environment.

I can add a `-Dkeepgoing` on the `ant` command line and use that, but I would rather have the `ant -k` apply to everything.

Answer (score 0):

The property `sun.java.command` contains the command line options provided to Ant:

### build.xml

```xml
<project>
    <condition property="keep-going-set" value="true" else="false">
        <contains string="${sun.java.command}" substring="-keep-going"/>
    </condition>
    <echo>keep-going-set: ${keep-going-set}</echo>
</project>
```

### Output

```
$ ant -keep-going
[echo] keep-going-set: true
```

Comment: hmm... `sun.java.command` isn't in my `ant` properties.  We are using a rather old version of Ant (1.8.0).  I'll try it with a newer version.  Thanks!